# Google Pay on the web with 3ds

Tags: google-pay

I'm trying to implement Google pay on the web by this example: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/paymentrequest/tutorial.

When I remove "**PAN_ONLY**" from the example code, the button becomes invisible on my PC and on smartphone.

Under what conditions with the authentication method "**CRYPTOGRAM_3DS**" payment will be available?

I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

[Tokenized cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(data_security)) are only available from your Android device today, where there are the means to securely authenticate the transaction and [store sensitive information](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce) related to your forms of payment.

There are initiatives in the industry aiming at adding means of security and second factors to the web. These are expected to help the utilization of tokenization on the Web too.